# Upgrade a sideloaded Windows 8 app and maintain database

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, indexeddb, appx

I'm developing an app for personal use. I'm using IndexedDB for data storage. I don't want to submit it to the app store since it's for personal use. I've figured out how to create an appx and install it onto my machine with Windows Powershell. However, when I update the app and want to install the new update to my computer Powershell gives me an error saying the app must be uninstalled first. I can uninstall and reinstall to get the updates, but then the database is cleared.

Is there a simple way to update my app without clearing the database? Or do I have to write a backup/restore routine for my app? Thanks!

Comment: did you try incrementing the version number on the application package? With my apps (C# though), I only have to uninstall if the new package version is the same or older than the existing one.

Comment: @chuex You should make that the answer as that's exactly what needs to be done. :)

Comment: I have tried incrementing the fourth version number. I will try incrementing a higher one tomorrow and see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect it might have to do with your version number.  Did you try incrementing it on the application package? With my apps (C# though), I only have to uninstall if the new package version is the same or older than the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this scenario is directly supported, since sideloading of apps using PowerShell and a developer license is intended for development and testing purposes.

Your best bet would likely be to add functionality to your app to export the contents of the database (either to a file or to a database hosted in the cloud) prior to uninstall, and then to import the contents when you reinstall the updated app.

Again, it's worth bearing in mind that you're working in an unsupported scenario in that sideloading apps using a developer license isn't intended for long-term use of apps, but for development and testing.

May also be worth reviewing some of the documentation on the developer license:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974578.aspx

And this documentation on the supported scenarios for sideloading and how to enable them:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx

Hope that helps.

For more information on Windows Store app development, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: When you have an Enterprise Application, side-loading is pretty much the only option available. Of course using a developer license wouldn't be ideal, but side-loading in _general_ as mentioned by the OP is a valid scenario.

Comment: @GotDibbs The relevant documentation says otherwise. It's pretty explicit that side-loading via developer license is only for development and testing. Not for using an app on an ongoing basis, which is how I interpreted the OP's scenario. Note that I'm not saying that it won't work, just that it's unsupported.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, when I say side-loading *in general* I mean one that is pushed *without* a developer license but still sideloaded. Check out this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx ... as well on the Windows 8 Enterprise page under App Deployment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/enterprise-edition.aspx